# Changing a character column into a continuous column, by dividing them into sections (1,2,3,4)

Tags: r, regression

I have a data set I'm trying to run a glm regression on, however it contains characters as age limit, race, and comorbidity class. I would like to change those columns into a continuous variable so the regression can accept it. Data below, I want to change the TBI.irace2 into (Hispanic=1, Black=2, white=3, and other=4) same with age (age 18-28=1, 29-46=2, 47-64=3, and >64=4) and with NISS (NISS 0-10=1, NISS 11-20=2, NISS 21-30=3, and NISS 31-40=4, NISS41-50=5, NISS 51-60=6, NISS 61-70=7, NISS>70= 8)

Please find summary of data below

```
TBI.crani = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TBI.vte = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TBI.FEMALE = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), TBI.iracecat2 = c("Whites", 
"Whites", "Whites", "Hispanics", "Whites", "Blacks"), TBI.agecat = c("Age 47-64", 
"Age 29-46", "Age > 64", "Age 29-46", "Age 18-28", "Age 18-28"
), TBI.nisscategory = c("NISS 21-30", "NISS 11-20", "NISS 21-30", 
"NISS 11-20", "NISS 11-20", "NISS 0-10"), TBI.LOS = c(5, 8, 1, 
3, 19, 1), TBI.hospitalteach = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), TBI.largebedsize = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), TBI.CM_ALCOHOL = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), TBI.CM_ANEMDEF = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TBI.CM_BLDLOSS = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TBI.CM_CHF = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TBI.CM_CHRNLUNG = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TBI.CM_COAG = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0), TBI.CM_HYPOTHY = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TBI.CM_LYTES = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TBI.CM_METS = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TBI.CM_NEURO = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TBI.CM_OBESE = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TBI.CM_PARA = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TBI.CM_PSYCH = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), TBI.CM_TUMOR = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TBI.CM_WGHTLOSS = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TBI.UTI = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TBI.pneumonia = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TBI.AMI = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TBI.sepsis = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TBI.arrest = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TBI.spineinjury = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TBI.legfracture = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TBI_time_to_surg.NEW = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I think your data is missing an opening `structure(list` part.

Comment: Inform yourself about dummy encoding, treatment contrasts and polynomial contrasts.

Comment: @MartinGal yes it is, once I put the code it disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small little tip, provide a small sample set that is just big enough to address your question.

```
library(data.table)

# took a small sample and changed one value to Asian
dt <- data.table(
  TBI.FEMALE = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), 
  TBI.iracecat2 = as.character(c("Whites", "Whites", "Asian", "Hispanics", "Whites", "Blacks"))
)

# define race groups, and note I did not define Asian
convert_race <- c("Hispanics" = 1, "Blacks" = 2, "Whites" = 3) # other will all be not defined

dt[, TBI.irace2 := lapply(TBI.iracecat2, function(x) convert_race[x]), by = TBI.iracecat2]
dt[is.na(TBI.irace2), TBI.irace2 := 4]

dt

#    TBI.FEMALE TBI.iracecat2 TBI.irace2
# 1:          0        Whites          3
# 2:          0        Whites          3
# 3:          1         Asian          4
# 4:          0     Hispanics          1
# 5:          1        Whites          3
# 6:          0        Blacks          2
```

Comment: @Merjn, I'm getting this error msg
 could not find function ":="

Comment: I use the data.table package